# how to start an activity inside fragment viewpager

Tags: android, android-intent, android-viewpager, fragment, android-context

I'm creating a swipeable Sherlock tab. I used this tutorial to do it:

[Android ActionBarSherlock ViewPager Tabs Tutorial](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-actionbarsherlock-viewpager-tabs-tutorial/)

However when I want to start an activity from inside of a fragment (for example FragmentTab1) I need context to create intent and start activity.
I'm in the Fragment class and don't have access to context!
I can't use getActivity() too, because FragmentTab1 is created inside of getItem() function in FragmentPagerAdapter class.
What should I do?!

Comment: come on man really, you keep fragments inside Activity not the other way around

Comment: please read the link and then write a comment man!!! :(

Comment: with all due respect, kindly have Toolbar (v7) with SlidingTabLayout it would certainly save you time and give you enough flexibility, https://developer.android.com/samples/SlidingTabsBasic/src/com.example.android.common/view/SlidingTabLayout.html

Comment: I know. but I want to hide put actionbar  and have tab except actionbar. Sherlock is for this purpose .

Answer (score 1):

Sherlock Fragments works with getSherlockActivity() instead of getActivity()
You should try using

`getSherlockActivity().startActivity(...)`

Comment: getSherlockActivity() is good when I start a fragment from sherlockFragmentActivity, not from FragmentPagerAdapter!

Answer (score 0):

> I'm in the Fragment class and don't have access to context!

Yes, you do. Call `getActivity()` to return the `Activity` that is hosting this fragment. `Activity` inherits from `Context`.

> I can't use getActivity() too, because FragmentTab1 is created inside of getItem() function in FragmentPagerAdapter class.

So? That does not somehow magically cause the `getActivity()` method to vanish.

For some reason, you are using ActionBarSherlock, which has been deprecated for about 20 months by its author. If your fragment is a `SherlockFragment`, you will want to call `getSherlockActivity()` instead.

Comment: can you read the link I put in my post and change FragmentTab1 and start an sample activity on it?!

Comment: @user3212159: There is nothing in that tutorial that would be a trigger to start an activity (action bar item, button, etc.). You may wish to edit your question and explain, **completely and precisely**, what you mean by "start an sample activity on it".

Comment: suppose we have an activity(myActivity for example). I should start activity this way: `startActivity(new Intent(getSherlockActivity() , myActivity.class));` . but it does not work and returns exception error;

Comment: @user3212159: Use LogCat to examine the Java stack trace associated with your exception: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this If you do not understand what the stack trace is telling you, ask a fresh Stack Overflow question where you paste in all relevant code, plus the stack trace, to try to get assistance.

Comment: Getting - java.lang.IllegalStateException: No tab known for tag null when trying to launch Intent inside fragment, please help.